# Serving multiple sites with Nginx on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I am running Nginx on Ubuntu and it works fine with localhost.
But i want to know how do we create multiple sites with Nginx with localhost on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new `server { }` block with the new site configuration (in the config file on `sites-available` folder).

If you create a separated config file for each website is easier to enable/disable it, you just have to create/remove a symbolic link for the configuration on `sites-enabled`.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a blog on setting up multiple sites with Nginx on Ubuntu, you can check that at [Configure Nginx for multiple sites on Ubuntu](http://dvsuresh.me/blog/2014/01/29/configure-nginx-for-multiple-websites-on-a-vps/)